# The Derivative Of Strictly Increasing Functions

Tags: calculus

Prove that is a function $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on an interval $[a, b]$ then $f'(x) \geq 0$ on $(a, b)$

Let us suppose the contrary that $f'(x)$ is greater than $0$ less than $0$ or equal to $0$ for some $x$ in $(a, b)$. Now let $f'(x_0)<0$, Now if $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$ then there exists an interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ in which $f'(x)<0$ then in that interval $f(x)$ is decreasing which is a contradiction to the given hypothesis. So $f'(x) \geq0$ on $(a, b)$
But I don't know hot to prove this when $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=x_0$

Comment: There is a similar theorem which can be modified per the remark below (not a direct answer to your question though).

Theorem: Suppose $f$ is  continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then $f$ is (strictly) increasing on $[a,b]$ if $f′>0$ on $(a,b)$.

Proof: We  will show that when $b\ge x > y \ge a$, it  implies that $f(x)> f(y)$.   Consider $\frac{f(x)−f(y)}{x−y}$, then by the MVT there exists some $c\in(y,x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)−f(y)}{x−y}=f′(c)$, which is greater than 0. Therefore, as $x−y >0$, we have $f(x)−f(y)>0$.

Comment: Remark: The reverse statement is not true.  For example, $f(x) =x^3$ is a strictly increasing function with its derivative $0$ at $x= 0$.  One can modify this statement by the following one: $f$ is a non-decreasing function on $[a,b]$ if and only if $f′≥0$ on $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is  increasing and differentiable on $[a,b]$ then
$$
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \ge 0
$$
for all $x, y \in [a,b]$ with $x \ne y$, and therefore
$$
 f'(x) = \lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \ge 0 \, .
$$
The continuity of $f'$ is not needed for this conclusion.

Comment: I think the $x\neq y$ should be $y>x$, am I missing something?

Comment: @omer: No, it holds for $y<x$ as well. In that case $f(y) \le f(x)$, so that the fraction becomes non-negative.